# Network analysis (with slopes)

Tags: qgis, slope, qgis-network-analysis

Using the QGIS network analysis (layers) command, I can calculate the maximum areas that a "bus stop" point can serve by determining a distance X.

However, I would like this distance to vary according to the slope of the street, which this a third layer.

For example:

- for streets with a slope of 0% I can walk 600m.
- for slopes of 5% I can only walk 500m,
- for slopes of 10 or more I can only walk 300m.

This rule will vary according to a table, where I will ponder the distances. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Split your network lines into short segments. Use [Densify by interval](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdensifygeometriesgivenaninterval), then [explode lines](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines).
2. Assign the slope value of the corresponding layer to each of the segments created in step 1 as a new attribute.
3. Create a new `speed` attribute field, based on the slope from step 2.
4. Run network tools, go to Advanced Parameters and for `Speed field [optional]` select the field created in step 3.